# How to write a groovy testcase for a function that returns the string representation of a json object?

Tags: java, testing, groovy, groovy-eclipse

I have a function called `userLogin()` that takes the input (username and password) of a login page as parameters and returns the string representation of a Json object that contains the details of the user who is trying to login.

My Function:

```
public String userLogin(String strUser, String strPswrd) throws Exception

{

    String strResult = null;
    String strUserlevel = null;
    String strDate = null;
    String strId = null;
    int nUserID = 0;
    int nParam = 0;
    StringBuilder sbSql = null;
    JSONObject oJson = null;

    ResultSet oRs = null;
    Root oRoot = null;
    PreparedStatement oPrStmt = null;

    try{
        oRoot = Root.createDbConnection(null);
        oJson = new JSONObject();

        sbSql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username =? AND Password = ? AND deleteflag =0 ");
        oPrStmt = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(sbSql.toString());
        nParam =0;
        oPrStmt.setString(++nParam, strUser);
        oPrStmt.setString(++nParam, strPswrd);
        oRs =oPrStmt.executeQuery();
        if(oRs.next()){
            nUserID = oRs.getInt("userlevel");

            strUserlevel = oRs.getString("users");
            strDate = oRs.getString("lastlogin");
            strId = oRs.getString("id");
            strUser = strUser.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + strUser.substring(1);
            oJson.put("status", "success");
            oJson.put("ID", strId);
            oJson.put("userID", nUserID);
            oJson.put("userlevel", strUserlevel);
            oJson.put("lastlogin", strDate);
            oJson.put("username", strUser);
        }
        strResult = oJson.toString();

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strResult;

}
```

Currently, I have installed the groovy-eclipse plugin from the Groovy/Grails Tool suite.I have watched some Youtube video's and read some tutorials on how to write groovy test cases but don't know how to implement it for my function.Can someone help me as I am new to using this tool .

Comment: have you already take a look at the spock framework?

Comment: iam using JUNIT 4

Comment: and not using spock framework

Comment: so, take a look at the spock framework. It will help you to write tests in groovy and also solves other problems. AFAIK, it hat a JUNIT4 compatible runner

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to move the DB connection to a constructor, property or factory method so it can be supplied via the tests.

```
class YourClass {
    PreparedStatement newPreparedStatement(String sql) {
        Root.createDbConnection(null).con.prepareStatement(sql)
    }
    String userLogin(String strUser, String strPswrd) throws Exception {
        def oPrStmt = newPreparedStatement("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username =? AND Password = ? AND deleteflag =0 ")
        // all the rest of your code from "nParam = 0" on
    }
}
```

With that, you could do something like this:

```
@Grab('org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19')
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*

import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Spy
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnit
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoRule

final class UserLoginTests {
    @Rule
    public final MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()
    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement statement
    @Mock
    private ResultSet results

    @InjectMocks @Spy
    private YourClass yours

    @Test
    void testUserLogin() {
        when(yours.newPreparedStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(statement)
        when(statement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(results)
        when(results.next()).thenReturn(...)

        String json = yours.userLogin('user', 'pass')
        assert json == 'literal json string'
      //or
        def map = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
        assert map.containsKey('something')
        // etc.
      //or
        // look into org.skyscreamer.JsonAssert
    }
}
```